# Dynamically added element id is null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm new to angularJS. When I click a button it will show a dialog, the dialog's html code is:

```
<img id="imgId" ng-src="{{imgSrc}}">
```

In controller, when I try to access `imgId` using JavaScript it showing null. Same with the JQuery.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('imgId')); // null
```

Here is my code:

```js
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']).
controller('mainController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.showCustomDialog = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      template: '{{hello}}<img id="imgId" ng-src="{{imgSrc}}">',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose: true
    });

    function DialogController($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.hello = "Hello World";
      $scope.imgSrc = "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScku8D7qo2hWD-eqb_WKTVjMjjiJFLo7uDQQ4RZWRNw9TJ-j7nYg";

      $timeout(function() {
        console.log(document.getElementById('imgId'));
        console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById('imgId')));
      });

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-controller="mainController" ng-cloak>
  <md-button ng-click="showCustomDialog($event)" class="md-primary">Show Dialog</md-button>

  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H9VoNRjfUrLPbm2Cm6i0))

Comment: You should use controller to access it. But what do you want to get with it? Why are you trying to fetch the HTML element? In angular, inside controllers, you should care about model and not HTML.. it is a different approach compared to jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the dialog a chance to render, before you can get a reference to it.

Wrap the `getElementById` calls in a `$timeout`:

```
$timeout(function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('imgId'));
    console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById('imgId')));
});
```

Keep in mind that you need to include the `$timeout` in your controller:

```
function DialogController($scope, $timeout) {
```

Here's a working example using your plunker's code:

```js
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']).
controller('mainController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.showCustomDialog = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      template: '{{hello}}<img id="imgId" ng-src="{{imgSrc}}">',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose: true
    });

    function DialogController($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.hello = "Hello World";
      $scope.imgSrc = "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScku8D7qo2hWD-eqb_WKTVjMjjiJFLo7uDQQ4RZWRNw9TJ-j7nYg";

      $timeout(function() {
        console.log(document.getElementById('imgId'));
        console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById('imgId')));
      });

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-controller="mainController" ng-cloak>
  <md-button ng-click="showCustomDialog($event)" class="md-primary">Show Dialog</md-button>

  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```